# My PHP form isn't returning anything from $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a relatively simple PHP form. When I'm using `print_r($_POST);` I'm not receiving anything back. Just this result:

```
`Array
  (
  )
  1`
```

My form is pretty simple:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="zip-<?php echo $atts['class']; ?>">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="<?php echo $column1; ?>" <?php echo $inlineStyle ?>>
                <div class="lds-facebook hide"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                <input type="text" name="zip" class="zip">
            </div>
            <div class="<?php echo $column2 ?>">
                <button type="submit" class="submit" name="submit">
                  <?php echo $buttonValue; ?>
                  <i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The goal of the form is to simply post and then redirect to a page depending on the value received from the input. Any thoughts?

```
public static function find_zip_widget( $atts, $content = null ) { 
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'class' => 'class'
), $atts));

    // Set classes for rows
    if($atts['class'] == 'home'){
        $column1 = 'col-md-6 col-12 my-auto text-center border-underline';
        $column2 = 'col-md-6 col-12';
        $buttonValue = 'FIND HELP RIGHT NOW';
        $inlineStyle = '';
    }

    if($atts['class'] == 'widget'){
        $column1 = 'col-md-5 col-5 offset-2 offset-md-0 my-auto';
        $column2 = 'col-md-7 col-5 my-auto';
        $buttonValue = 'SUBMIT';
        $inlineStyle = 'style="border-bottom: 3px solid #9EA2A4 !important;min-height: 30px;"';
    }

    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="zip-<?php echo $atts['class']; ?>">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="<?php echo $column1; ?>" <?php echo $inlineStyle ?>>
                <div class="lds-facebook hide"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                <input type="text" name="zip" class="zip">
            </div>
            <div class="<?php echo $column2 ?>">
                <button type="submit" class="submit" name="submit">
                  <?php echo $buttonValue; ?>
                  <i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php    
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "Before if: ";
        echo  print_r($_POST); 
        echo "</pre>";
    ?>

    <?php 
        $states = get_categories( array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'taxonomy' => 'endeavors_location_state'
        ) );


        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $postalZip = $_POST["zip"];

            echo "<pre>";
            echo "After if: ";
            echo  print_r($_POST);
            echo "</pre>";

            echo '<br> <br> PostalZip: ' . $postalZip;

            ///REDIRECT FOR CITY, STATE, or other/////
            $ch = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$postalZip.'&key=AIzaSyBX_0qZmGBtiHrZMcjZfv6yL7NAbLiwnjc");
            // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=78210&key=AIzaSyBX_0qZmGBtiHrZMcjZfv6yL7NAbLiwnjc");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);
            $jsonResults = json_decode($output, true);



            $cityName = $jsonResults['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'];
            $stateName = $jsonResults['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name'];


            $cityName = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$cityName));
            $stateName = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$stateName));

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'endeavors_locations',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
              'numberposts' => -1
            );

            $cityFound = 0;
            $allCityLocations = get_posts( $args );
            foreach ($allCityLocations as $location) {
                $eachCity = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$location->post_name));
                echo $eachCity;

                if ($location->post_name === $cityName) {
                    $cityFound = 1;
                    echo $cityFound;
                }
            }

            if ($cityFound === 1) {
                wp_safe_redirect('/locations/'.$cityName);
                } else {
                foreach ($states as $state) {
                    if ($state->slug === $stateName) {
                         $stateFound = 1;
                    }
                }
                if ($stateFound === 1) {
                wp_safe_redirect('/state/'.$stateName);
                } else {
                    wp_safe_redirect('/all-locations/');
                }
            }
        }
    ///END OF REDIRECT FOR CITY, STATE, or other/////
    } //end function
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the PHP script.

Comment: I added the entire shortcode function.

Comment: if i may can you copy the html code from the developer tools and make a new php file and test it by itself that could shed some light

Comment: Done and done.....still not seeing anything new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script post to the server just fine, but before hitting the print_r($_POST) it gets redirect to  the same location. so print_r($_POST) was not executed . Please refer below image for additional info. There are two requests , one is post with 302 redirect. I suspect there maybe a javascript redirect involved.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I can definitely see my value submitting now. So why wouldn't my `if (isset($_POST['submit_value'])) { ` be firing?

Comment: That is something you need to investigate. Try adding a die() statement after print_r($_POST) to stop executing further php and rendering the HTML and let us know what you get :)

Comment: I added the `die()` and that seemed to show me the array of `$_POST`. So that's good. Looks like it is getting into the if isset too. Now I have a new problem to solve. Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: @Lz430 looking at the `isset($_POST['submit'])` portion you are calling `wp_safe_redirect`, meaning `$_POST` will be empty upon redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your script,(xampp , php 7.1.26 , mac Mojave) and it prints

```
Array ( [zip] => testvalue [submit] => )
```

I added `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` on top of the  tag.( you might have done the same) and for me it worked as expected.

silly but did just wanted to know whether you submitted the form? if not it will show an empty array

Comment: i might think the post variable is altered somehow. could be using a framework or something. i did exactly what you did and i didn't make any sense of it

Comment: Thank you both. I'm on WPengine running php 7.2. I don't believe there are any frameworks. I guess for sanity's sake, there's nothing wrong with my form markup or anything else if you guys are getting it to print, right?

Comment: to be honest i spotted a mark up thing that is not related to the issue
```<i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>``` used single quote :D

Comment: Talal, this is related to wordpress maybe. @Lz430  can you try the following solutions

1. Change the input name from 'zip ' to something unique 'yournamezip' just to check

2. change the action <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  

and see this helps

Comment: Ok, I've done both and I'm still getting nothing. I've even tried `echo  print_r($_POST['geoZip']); ` For reference the URL is here: https://endeavorsdev1.wpengine.com/all-locations/